# How to scrape date from li tag using beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I scraped all the li tags with specific class and got output :

```
<li>Aug 14-18, <a href="https://ai4good.org/fragile-earth-2021/">Fragile Earth 2021</a>, develop radically new technological foundations for advancing and meeting the Sustainable Development Goals. Online KDD-21 workshop.
</li>

<li>Aug 19-26, <a href="https://ijcai-21.org/">IJCAI-21: 30th Int. Joint Conference on Artificial Intelligence</a>. Montreal-themed Virtual Reality, Online.
</li>
```

I am able to scrape out the href and text separately,however I would also like to store the date in a column of dataframe or atleast get the dates seperately. Any idea how I can do that?

Here's the link to the website : https://www.kdnuggets.com/meetings/index.html#Y21-10

Comment: Try `link_text.split(', <')[0]` :)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what you have tried so far

Comment: Please include your code and what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup("""<li>Aug 14-18, <a href="https://ai4good.org/fragile-earth-2021/">Fragile Earth 2021</a>, develop radically new technological foundations for advancing and meeting the Sustainable Development Goals. Online KDD-21 workshop.
</li>

<li>Aug 19-26, <a href="https://ijcai-21.org/">IJCAI-21: 30th Int. Joint Conference on Artificial Intelligence</a>. Montreal-themed Virtual Reality, Online.
</li>""", "lxml")
dates = [x.text.split(',')[0] for x in soup.find_all('li')]
print(dates)
```

OUTPUT:

```
['Aug 14-18', 'Aug 19-26']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access specific elements using the [`.contents`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children) method:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = """
<li>Aug 14-18, <a href="https://ai4good.org/fragile-earth-2021/">Fragile Earth 2021</a>, develop radically new technological foundations for advancing and meeting the Sustainable Development Goals. Online KDD-21 workshop. </li>
<li>Aug 19-26, <a href="https://ijcai-21.org/">IJCAI-21: 30th Int. Joint Conference on Artificial Intelligence</a>. Montreal-themed Virtual Reality, Online. </li>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

dates = [tag.contents[0].strip(', ') for tag in soup.find_all("li")]
print(dates)
```

Output:

```
['Aug 14-18', 'Aug 19-26']
```